# is there any widely accepted syntax for writing post data in url?

Tags: url, post

You can give someone an url with get:

```
http://myserver.com/?var=val
```

But what to do with POST method ? I know that the program I put url into must support this, I do not know any browser that can (maybe with plugin possible), but is there widely accepted syntax to do it, for example I came up with this:

```
http://myserver.com/<var=val>
```

or maybe:

```
http://myserver.com/??var=val
http://myserver.com/?!var=val
http://myserver.com/!!var=val
http://myserver.com/!var=val
```

etc...
I'm writing a tool to do it , and I wonder if I must think on my own just like first guy who created e-mail and out of the air conceived `@` character since it was rarely used then...

The idea is that some services use post data and there is no way to send someone link to resource there. And yes I know that when there is post data that resource is not meant to be such easy passeable to people... but wait since when author of a website has to have power over what I can and can't do with his service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better introduce a separate argument for passing POST data to your tool. Mixing it together with URL would just cause confusion among your users. Remember that POST data be quite large, so you'd end up introducing features like loading POST data (or a value of an individual variable) from a file anyway.